# android change image button background

Tags: android, image, button, background

I cannot seem to change the background image of my image button. Heres the code i'm currently trying to use:

```
ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.showSportsButton);
imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab2_selected);
```

However this seem to be placing the new image on top of the old image leaving me with 2 images overlapping each other.

Does anyone know why this is??

Comment: I guess you'll have to use `.setImageResource` inherited from [`ImageView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29)

Comment: `please add imgButton.setImageResource(null);
imgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable. tab2_selected);`

Comment: What's the old image - the default one, meaning the grey (for example, depending of the Theme) imagE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For solving this question you should implement

```
imgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable. tab2_selected);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
imgButon.setBackground(getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_icon));
```

Answer (score 0):

in xml file, `<Button>`   write: `android:backgroud="@drawable/your_file"`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on same activity. If you are changing background of different activity first create the constructor then use object to change button.

```
Activity obj= new activity();
obj.imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab2_selected);
```

and also check that `oncreate()` method has `void` return type if you are using only `findviewbyid`.